# How to add MediaPlayer button in ActionBar - Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-actionbar, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to add just one sound item in the action bar, wherein the sound will automatically play when the app start and when I click on it, the sound will go off.

I also don't know how to pause it when the same icon is clicked.

Please help me. I'm just new to Android.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

private MediaPlayer mp;
Item btnplay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


 }


//inflate items in actionbar
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

boolean isPlaying = true;
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.btnplay) //whatever you named in xml
        {
            play();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

public void play() {
    mp = new MediaPlayer();        
    if (!isPlaying) {
    try
    {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("caketown.mp3"); 
        mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength()); 
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();//play sound
    }
    catch(Exception e) {}
    }
    else if (isPlaying) {
    mp.pause();
    }
 }
```

Here is my menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.xxx.MainActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/btnplay"
    android:title=""
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_volume_on"
    android:onClick="play"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>   
<menu>
```

Here is my logcat

```
12-18 14:58:05.933: E/Trace(18735): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-18 14:58:12.608: E/AndroidRuntime(18735): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 14:58:12.608: E/AndroidRuntime(18735): android.view.InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler play in class com.example.ttg.activity.MainActivity
12-18 14:58:12.608: E/AndroidRuntime(18735):    at android.view.MenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>(MenuInflater.java:217)
12-18 14:58:12.608: E/AndroidRuntime(18735):    at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(MenuInflater.java:417) 
12-18 14:58:12.608: E/AndroidRuntime(18735):    at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(MenuInflater.java:451)
12-18 14:58:12.608: E/AndroidRuntime(18735):    at android.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:188)
12-18 14:58:12.608: E/AndroidRuntime(18735):    at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:110)
12-18 14:58:12.608: E/AndroidRuntime(18735):    at com.example.ttg.activity.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:160)
12-18 14:58:12.608: E/AndroidRuntime(18735):    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2488)
12-18 14:58:12.608: E/AndroidRuntime(18735):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:406)
12-18 14:58:12.608: E/AndroidRuntime(18735):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:771)
12-18 14:58:12.608: E/AndroidRuntime(18735):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:3021)
12-18 14:58:12.608: E/AndroidRuntime(18735):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-18 14:58:12.608: E/AndroidRuntime(18735):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-18 14:58:12.608: E/AndroidRuntime(18735):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
12-18 14:58:12.608: E/AndroidRuntime(18735):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5042)
12-18 14:58:12.608: E/AndroidRuntime(18735):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native  Method)
12-18 14:58:12.608: E/AndroidRuntime(18735):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-18 14:58:12.608: E/AndroidRuntime(18735):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
12-18 14:58:12.608: E/AndroidRuntime(18735):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
12-18 14:58:12.608: E/AndroidRuntime(18735):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-18 14:58:12.608: E/AndroidRuntime(18735): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: play [interface android.view.MenuItem]
12-18 14:58:12.608: E/AndroidRuntime(18735):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
12-18 14:58:12.608: E/AndroidRuntime(18735):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
12-18 14:58:12.608: E/AndroidRuntime(18735):    at android.view.MenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>(MenuInflater.java:215)
12-18 14:58:12.608: E/AndroidRuntime(18735):    ... 18 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the complete code. You need rain.mp3 in res/raw directory

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Boolean keepPlaying = true;
MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        play();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void play() {

    if(keepPlaying) {
        try {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.rain);
            mp.start();//play sound

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            keepPlaying = false;
        }
    } else {
        mp.stop();
        keepPlaying = true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The app crashes. Please see again the codes, I've already edited it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: play [interface android.view.MenuItem]
> ```

Methods used with menu `onClick` attribute must take a single `MenuItem` argument.

Change

```
public void play()
```

to

```
public void play(MenuItem menuItem)
```

Comment: I've tried this, and the play(); in onOptionsItemSelected got an error, so I change it to play(item); The app now is not crashing but the sound is not playing, and whenever I click it an error in logcat is showing 'pause called in state 1'

Comment: Consider logging your exceptions in `play()` and not just silently ignoring them.

Comment: Can you show me how? I'm just new to this MediaPlayer. :(

Comment: For example in the catch block, `e.printStackTrace();`-